# DynamoDB + Quarkus - Odd type conversion

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, quarkus

I have a table / entity on DynamoDB that should be mapped with number as fields.

Example:

```
@RegisterForReflection
Foo {
     Integer myfield;
     ...
}
```

I noticed that the AWS SDK used by *quarkus-amazon-dynamodb* dependency is built in a odd way.

For example,the n() method of  *software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.AttributeValue*

return a java **String** instead of a **Number** type, so I have to convert the result with a clumsy **Integer.parseInt()**

```
public static Foo from(Map<String, AttributeValue> item) {
    final var output = new Foo();
    if (item != null && !item.isEmpty()) {
        output.setMyField(Integer.parseInt(item.get(MY_FIELD).n()));
    }
    return output;
}
```

The same happens if I have to fetch an item and use

**AttributeValue.builder().n()**

```
final Map<String, AttributeValue> key = new HashMap<>();
    key.put(Foo.MY_FIELD, AttributeValue.builder().n(input.toString()).build()); // too bad!!

    return GetItemRequest.builder()
            .tableName(TABLE_NAME)
            .key(key)
            .attributesToGet(Foo.MY_FIELD)
            .build();
```

Do I miss something ?

**PS**

The Quarkus dynamoDB documentation is [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-dynamodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not odd - that's just how AWS DynamoDB works. Numbers are represented as strings in DynamoDB and Quarkus has nothing to do with that. See the [API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html):

> **N** 
> An attribute of type Number. For example:
>
> "N": "123.45"
>
> Numbers are sent across the network to DynamoDB as strings, to
> maximize compatibility across languages and libraries. However,
> DynamoDB treats them as number type attributes for mathematical
> operations.
>
> Type: String